# Issues in eclipse editor

Tags: java, eclipse, character-encoding

The eclipse version that I am using is not able to read some of the special characters which are present in the code.

Below are the characters which eclipse is not able to read ..

```
{'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'æ','ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ð', 'ñ', 'ò','ó','ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ß', 'ø', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ý', 'þ', '×'}
```

It converts the above array into

```
{ '�', '�', '�', '�', '�', '�', '�','�', '�', '�', '�', '�', '�', '�', '�', '�', '�', '�', '�', '�','�', '�', '�', '�', '�', '�', '�', '�', '�', '�', '�', '�' }
```

Any idea how can we solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to change the 'Text file encoding' option. You can specify the default for this in the Preferences > General > Workspace page.

You can also change the value for an individual file on the file Properties > Resource page.

Of course you need to know what the encoding the file is using. UTF-8 would be an initial guess.

Comment: Worked for me by using ISO-8859-1 as the encoding.. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @SiddhantJain mark greg-449 's post as an accepted answer. There's a check mark under the upvote/downvote buttons at the left side of the post.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open eclipse project properties
2. Set "Text file encoding" to **UTF-8** as it is shown on the picture below.

[image]

3. Accept the dialog.

Comment: Thanks Rafael for the info